# How to efficiently program a big/big left join query in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, join

Our problem lies in performing a left join on two large tables (both having millions of entries).

The first one is a table that contains input supplied by the end-user of our program. It contains answers to a variety of questions. Every question belongs to a certain questionnaire. The most important columns are an identifier for the given response, an identifier for the questionnaire form, the datetime the answer is given and an identifier for the user that supplied the answer.

The second table contains information on daily progress of the users regarding the completion of questionnaires. It contains information on the amount of answers a certain user has given on a certain day for a given activity. The most important columns in this table are the user id, the questionnaire id and the date.

The second database is updated right after a new answer enters the first database. Updating is performed by code (workers) that runs on a different server. We would to like make the system robust against failure of this other server. An important step to ensure that the table with the results ('responses') remains in sync with the progress ('progress_questionnaires') table is to be able to check whether a combination of user_id, questionnaire_id and datetime from the 'responses' table is also present in the 'progress_questionnaires' table. A query that captures the required results, but does not perform on large databases (NxN, in which N is couple of millions entries), is displayed below.

A query that captures the required results is:

```
SELECT r.chapter_id, r.user_id, CAST(first_created as date) as date, 1 as original 
  FROM responses r 
  LEFT JOIN progress_questionnaires pq ON r.questionnaire_id = pq.questionnaire_id AND r.user_id = pq.user_id AND CAST(r.first_created as date) = pq.date
  WHERE pa.activity_id IS NULL 
  GROUP BY r.questionnaire_id, r.user_id, CAST(r.first_created as date)
```

As stated before, this query does capture the required results, but does not perform well on large tables. All key columns are properly indexed as far as we know.

We would be very happy if someone could help us out.

P.S. We are using MariaDB, SQL version 5.5.43. I hope I supplied al necessary information, but logically I would be happy to supply additional information where necessary.

Comment: The question lacks database schema, results of `EXPLAIN` and some statistics (like how many rows is returned, how many rows fit the join condition)

Comment: PS: it's weird that you use `GROUP BY` but don't use any aggregation functions.

Comment: Thanks for this quick reaction! I will add the required information tomorrow.